# Page Title Move for All Pages - Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

```
<div class="columns">
 <div class="column main">
    <div class="page-title-wrapper">
        <h1 class="page-title">
        <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">My Account</span>    
        </h1>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**How can i move `page-title-wrapper` div between `columns` and `column main` ?**

I have try this one by one but not working:

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" after="columns"/>

<move element="category.image" destination="page.title.wrapper" after="page.main.title" /> 

<move element="page.main.title"  destination="headerlinks" after="columns" />

<move element="page.title.wrapper" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>     

<move element="page.main.title" destination="headerlinks" before="-"/>
```

Any help will be appreciated.... Thanks in advanced.

Comment: <move element="page.main.title" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add `page.main.title` block inside `column main` then use below line

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="main" before="-" />
```

Or if you want to move that inside `columns` then use below line

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns" before="-" />
```

**UPDATE :**

`default.xml` file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="columns" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to add title inside `column` tag in **My Account** page then please create this file (`customer_account_index.xml`) inside your theme/module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="columns" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have try one by one your both script but not working for me.

Comment: Where you're adding this line? Can you please tell me that?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Pkg/csw/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: Please add this line inside <body> tag and then clear and flush magento cache once and check.

Comment: it's already  in <body> tag and done commands

Comment: @JimitBhavsar, I've added default.xml file content in answer. Please try to add only that content and remove your content once and check. I've tested that with default Luma theme and both are working here.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help then.

Comment: i have remove all my script and only put your script and run commands but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102006/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-jimit-bhavsar).

Comment: Answer updated. Please review once and let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: yes, it's working in customer_account_index.xml file, thanks. approved your answer.

Comment: Happy coding. :) +1 for acceptance. :)